# Абсолютное позиционирование на Android

Tags: android, html, css

Всем привет!

Смотрите пример 
http://jsfiddle.net/chaika_sv/z897oacL/
(хочу сделать знак рубля новый на сайте)

Код везде работает хорошо, кроме Opera Mini на Android. На Android абсолютно спозиционированная зачёркивающая линия оказывается почему-то где-то внизу под Р.

HTML

```
<span class="rouble">
    P<div class="rouble__dash">–</div>
</span>
```

CSS

```
.rouble__dash{
    left: 0;
    line-height: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 11px;
}
.rouble{
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Используйте юникодовский символ рубля? А в вашей ситуации внутри строчного элемента (span) лежит блочный (div), отсюда могут быть проблемы в старых браузерах. Добавьте span'у `display:inline-block;`, и да, % оперы мини для андроида ничтожно мал, думаю, никто даже всерьёз её не рассматривает.

Comment: Я не использую символ рубля вообще - в span у меня обычный символ Р, и относительно него абсолютно спозиционирован div с дефисом, который должен перечёркивать символ Р. В старых браузерах нет проблем, проблема только на Андройде.

Comment: Это был вопрос: Почему Вы используете костыли, вместо юникодовского символа рубля? Зачем Вам лишняя разметка к тому же семантически и логически неверная?

Comment: Я пробовал использовать юникодовский символ, как на http://cbr.ru. Опять же всё ок, но опять же на Android в этом случае вместо спецсимвола рубля приходится подставлять что-то типа "руб." или обычного "Р".

Comment: А Вы в курсе, что mini со времён своего зарождения предназначена для устройств, неспособных полноценно отображать вэб-контент, и все её запросы проводятся через адаптирующие сервера?

Comment: Нет, этого я не знал) И всё-таки по существу, как считаете, проблема решаема?